# How to connect to OAuth from SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, pingfederate

I have a scenario where my SharePoint application has to connect to a webservice after authenticating with PingFederate.

When I try the sample code from PingFederate, I am getting the error `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing` from both the webservice end point and the PingFederate server.

What are the necessary headers needed at my end and the service/pingfederate ends?

Answer (score 0):

In this very specifc scenario you will need to add exactly that header in this format

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.org
```

Headers are required depending on your code needs, you will find the most comon here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints